# How to convert List type _JsonMap to List type Map in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I make a call to my api I get the following result:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to transform the result into a MAP type list.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<_JsonMap> jsonMaps = [...]; // assume this is your list of _JsonMap objects
List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = jsonMaps.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>().toList();
```